# Recommendation: Tool for import files/folder - that doesn't duplicate duplicates

Tags: file-management, import, archive, archival

I need help finding a way of archiving my photographs. My requirements are very few:

- I want to copy/move a set or files or a folder into my photos-folder where i have subfolders named "yyyu-mm-dd" (=EXIF date taken)
- When doing this, the tool needs to avoid importing the same photo twice
  (Like with Acdsee: The second time I import the same image it adds " (1)" to second files name, then " (2)" to the third and so on...)
- Should work in Windows or Linux. Preferably Windows.
- Would be nice to be able to select a set of files to import rather then a whole folder.

I used Adobe Lightroom for a while but it was too expensive for this simple task. But I liked it. I could just select a couple of files in windows and drag'n'drop them into Lightroom and the importer would pop up and it didn't import duplicates and so on. So simple.

After that I switched to Acdsee. Liked it a lot but the import UI feels a bit behind and cumbersome. It didn't handle duplicates in a good way, as i mentioned before. Have a missed any configuration for this?

Using the windows build-in photo-importer can only import files from a camera, not a folder or a selection of files.

Can you recommend a tool for this that is either not as expensive as Lightroom or open source?

Comment: Writing a shell script for that would take about one minute; take it as a good opportunity to learn it!

Comment: I've actually considered it. But I would prefer something with a GUI so would a nice overview what I'm doing.

Comment: ... also common! There must be a program that exists that can handle these simple requirements!

Comment: There probably is a program that does it. Finding one that can be trusted for Windows requires wading through many that require a healthy dose of skepticism. That's the nature of the Windows ecosystem (an observation not a criticism). That price (paying for Lightroom as the safe alternative) and the sort of work *I* do makes Linux a better choice for *me*. I use a free and open source program called Rapid Photo Downloader written in Python. It does exactly what you want (except the Windows/Mac part).

Comment: @benrudgers : Thank you for the great response. I could map the windows file server to my linux laptop and import over the network :/ . I'll have a look at Rapid Photo Downloader as soon as I can. Better Linux than nothing! Thnx again!

Comment: What is this question really about? Archiving or importing to some program? LR does not archive anything. Importing to LR catalog and making copies of that catalog only makes a backup of the databse. It does not backup the images.

Answer (score 1):

I use the free and open source program [Rapid Photo Downloader](http://www.damonlynch.net/rapid/). It allows renaming files and creating directories. It can also "back up" files to a different location while downloading to the primary location. And it is, in my opinion, rapid enough.

The [FAQ](http://www.damonlynch.net/rapid/faq.html) indicates Linux only, but it may be useful on an heterogeneous network. It also suggests that porting to OSX or Windows might be practical.