# How to import photos without duplicates?

Tags: software-recommendation, backup

I organize my pictures using a folder structure on an external hard drive. Every time I import new pictures from my camera, I move this pictures in these folders manually. This process is tedious, and in many cases, I have duplicate pictures in different folders.

I would like to know if there is any open-source software which would allow me to import pictures from my camera, skipping images that are already in my folder structure.

In the past, I used Apple iPhoto, which did a great job in that sense, but now I am looking for a suitable alternative.

Comment: Perhaps, once you've copied them off your camera/media, you could delete them from your camera/media so there's no chance of re-importing them again?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is really on topic here or whether it should be on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead. However, at minimum we would need to know what platform you are on.

Comment: @twalberg thanks for advice, in my specific case I need to keep some picture in the camera, so I have some risk of diplicates

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that by keeping some pictures on the camera(sd card) is that the software that checks for duplicates with find photos on the sd card, that you have already culled from your hard drive. I use Lightroom, which isn't foss, but it does check for duplicates, but I have the aforementioned issue. If you're not culling any photos than their might be something that gets the job done like you want. I personally do it by hand which isn't that difficult. I have developed scripts that do a lot of the other work.

Comment: Maybe it help us if you were to explain your entire workflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been double posted at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51843/software-to-import-photos-from-my-camera-without-duplicates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommendation: Tool for import files/folder - that doesn't duplicate duplicates](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/91596/recommendation-tool-for-import-files-folder-that-doesnt-duplicate-duplicates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Digikam** is a cross-platform application that has the ability to import only images that have not already been imported. The feature is confusingly called "Download New". See [Using a Digital Camera With digiKam](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-graphics/digikam/using-camera.html).
- To remove some of the tedium of manually organizing images, you can use `exiftool` to rename and organize files into folders by date-time:

  ```
  exiftool -v -P -q -fileOrder FileName \
     '-FileName<${DateTimeOriginal}%-c.%le' \
     '-FileName<${DateTimeOriginal}.\${ImageCount}%-c.%le' \
     '-FileName<${DateTimeOriginal}.\${SubSecTimeOriginal}%-c.%le' \
     '-d %Y%m%d/%Y%m%d-%H%M%S' \
     -ext jpg -ext mov -ext mp4 -ext avi -ext cr2 -ext raf -ext dng .
  ```

  Then you can use `rsync` to copy only the changed files to your hard drive:

  ```
  rsync -FatHz -h --info=progress2 [source]/ [destination]/
  ```
- You can write your own scripts to keep track of files that have already been copied from the SD card. For example, on Linux, the following can be used:

  ```
  destination="path/to/incoming/folder/"
  for file in *.jpg ; do
     if ! grep "$file" list.txt ; then
        echo "$file" >> list.txt
        cp "$file" "$destination"
     fi
  done
  ```

  This approach can be improved by tracking checksums or other file metadata to avoid problems with filenames repeating at 0001.

Answer (score 1):

You could use duplicate finder like [Duplicate Photo Finder](http://www.duplicate-finder.com/photo.html) or [VisiPics](http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page)
both works ok, you might find one or another clumsy to work with, but it really depends on your usage of older software.

Answer (score -1):

So, the file name is what makes an image unique for system's understanding.

So, if you are on PC and copy the file you already copied, PC will give you an  alert for the File already exists.

Not happening in your case?

Comment: it is a different case, I have a different folder structure source/target but same file name